# Export Sheet to PDF with Page Numbers

Tags: google-apps-script

Tried using this to export a sheet to PDF. Everything works but the page numbers won't appear. Can anyone let me know why? Thanks

```
  var url = ss.getUrl(); //gets url 
  url = url.replace(/edit/,''); 

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
  '&size=letter' + 
  '&portrait=false' + 
  '&fitw=true' + 
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +  
  '&pagenumbers=true&gridlines=false' + 
  '&fzr=true' +  
  '&gid=GID'

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, { 
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token 
      } 
    }); 
      var blob = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');
```

Comment: If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 3):

How about this modification?

#### From :

```
pagenumbers=true
```

#### To :

```
pagenum=RIGHT
```

#### Result :

[image]

In my environment, also I had confirmed that `pagenumbers=true` doesn't work. So I had used this. But if it changes from `pagenum=RIGHT` to `pagenum=LEFT` and `pagenum=CENTER`, the position is always the right side. I don't know whether this is a bug. I'm sorry.